# JMeter Oracle JDBC configuration

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter

I have a problem connecting to Oracle from JMeter. I received this error:

```
Response code: null 17002 
Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"
```

I have ojdb14, 6, 5 and more in /lib
added class12 in /lib and /lib/ext

Then in test plan, I added jars to classpath, all pointing to jar lib.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

could it be in how to write the JDBC:

Comment: can NOT post images till I have some credits!

Comment: Well can you tnsping the database from the command-line?  throwing extra jars in the mix isn't going to make things better.  ojdbc14 is ancient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have Oracle JDBC driver somewhere in JMeter Classpath
2. Make sure you have configured network adapter in the virtual machine in Bridge mode (not "host-only", not "NAT") so the virtual machine would have its own IP address.
3. Make sure port 1521 (or whatever is used by Oracle) is not blocked by OS firewall. Check if you are able to connect to the port using i.e. telnet client
4. Add JDBC Connection Configuration test element and provide JDBC url of your Oracle instance along with credentials there.